# Status 400 (Bad Request) when creating content type in strapi

Tags: strapi

Im trying to create a content type in strapi using the content type builder plugin. This worked good so far for 6 content types but when I tried to create a content type named "Equipment" i get an Status code 400 (Bad Request).
Creating a content name with any other name still works perfectly well without any errors.

console log:

```
[2021-11-09T08:52:02.874Z] debug POST /content-type-builder/content-types (23 ms) 400
```

browser console:

[image: browser console]

I saw similar posts on [GitHub](https://github.com/strapi/strapi/issues/5095), which included errors due to a leading number in the name, but this isn't the case here.

Strapi Version: 3.6.8 (node v16.10.0)